# Why does Delphi add a blank field to the end of every TObject instance?

Tags: delphi, rtti, tobject

While playing around with Delphi and the RTTI for a small debug tool I'm working on, I noticed that Delphi always allocates extra zeroes at the end of every class instance.

This is the same in both 32bit and 64bit, just the sizes are different. Here's what happens in 64bit for `TObject.Create`:

- `TObject.InstanceSize` return 16.
- These 16 bytes are allocated for the instance and initialised to zeroes.
- The first 8 bytes are assigned a pointer to `TClass`.
- The second 8 bytes are left as zeroes.

Any sub-class will always have these final 8 bytes of zeroes after the other fields.

My question is this: why does Delphi include these trailing zeroes in the instance? The only reason I can come up with is that it is some sort of safety feature, but I am unable to see how this would help.

Comment: It is reserved for hidden pointer field that can be used for instance synchronization through `System.TMonitor`

Comment: My question has been closed as a duplicate. While I am happy to close my question as I got the answer I was looking for, I don't think that the question is really a duplicate. In my case I had no idea about TMonitor so my search didn't lead me to that other question. I supposed my question will now lead other to the other question.

Comment: Being closed as a duplicate is not a punishment. It is meant to consolidate answers to the single place even when questions may seem to be different, but the answers are the same. You didn't know what is that field for, but the proper answer would basically have to repeat everything that is said on the linked Q/A. There is no need to do that and if anyone has the similar question as you did they will be able to find their answer there by following your post.